# NSDatePicker Error

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsdate, nsdatepicker

Ever time I try to make a string in xcode it won't work can someone point out what's wrong and help please

```
        NSString *date = self.DatePicker.date;
```

This is the error "Incompatible pointer types initializing 'NSString * strong' with an expression of type 'NSDate *'"

Comment: "can someone point out what's wrong" - two things are terribly wrong: 1. this is **unrelated to Xcode,** 2. you haven't bothered **reading the documentation nor trying to understand the error message**.

Comment: 1. It is related to xcode because the error was in xcode 2. I did google it and looked at about 5 pages and nothing was there

Comment: @Programer1038: xcode is an ide, not a compiler!!!

Comment: @Programer1038 1. Nor a programming language, nor an API. You can develop iOS apps while completely avoiding Xcode (I do that, for the record). 2. If you read the official documentation of `NSDatePicker`, you would have found out that its `date` property contains an `NSDate`, and not an `NSString`.

Comment: What are you talking about. Not everybody is a IOS genius, some just started

Comment: I did not even say compiler

Answer (score 3):

`self.DatePicker.date;` returns date.

You are storing  it in `NSString`.

Use:

```
NSDate *date = self.DatePicker.date;
```

Then if you want to store it in string then use:

```
NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:[NSDate date] 
                                                  dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle 
                                                  timeStyle:NSDateFormatterFullStyle];
```

Comment: You did a great job with the example, +1.